Door bottom lock
I do not know the exact name of this part of the door which is missing in the door. Does any one know what name is that? Is there any way to fix this easily?


If the blue is where air is coming in, then you are looking for weatherstripping.

Try googling ‘foot bolt door lock’. There’s a bunch of other ways to name it, but that’ll get you started.
